# Retornando dados do Firebase em um Array

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, array, firebase

Então, tô com um pequeno problema que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum.
Estou utilizando o firebase database em conjunto com um microcontrolador ESP8266.
O ESP8266 envia os dados do sensor para o firebase, e através de uma página HTML quero visualizar os dados e criar um gráfico.

O trecho de código que utilizo para acessar a database e retornar os dados é esse:

```
   var refTanque1 = db.ref("Dados tanque 1 (Caixa d'agua)");


   refTanque1.on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
     let key = snapshot.val();

     valornivelT1 = key['2- Nivel do tanque'];
     valorvolT1 = key['3- Volume do tanque'];
     var data = valorvolT1; 
     dataArr = [];
     dataArr.push(data);

     console.log(dataArr);

   });
```

O que recebo de retorno são vários arrays com somente uma posição nesse formato:
[9.97]
[9.96]
[9.97]
[9.86]
[9.92]
[9.97]

O que eu desejo receber é um array com todos esses elementos separados por vírgula, exemplo:
[9.97, 9.96, 9.97, 9.86, 9.92, 9.97]

Já tentei utilizar o método push, join, e tudo que imaginei mas sempre sem sucesso.
Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o `on('child_added')`, use o `once('value')`:

```js
var refTanque1 = db.ref("Dados tanque 1 (Caixa d'agua)");

refTanque1.once('value', function(listaSnapshot) {
     dataArr = [];
     listaSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
         let key = snapshot.val();

         valornivelT1 = key['2- Nivel do tanque'];
         valorvolT1 = key['3- Volume do tanque'];
         var data = valorvolT1; 
         dataArr.push(data);
     })
     console.log(dataArr);
});
```